# how to assign output of command to another variable in shell

Tags: linux, shell

how do i assign the output of command to another variable in shell,
here what i tried.

```
summary = `grep -A 4 '#HM based Segregation FEP (WNS)(TNS)' some_file | awk '{print $2, $3}' | sed 's/,=,//g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/based Segregation,//g' | sed 's/(\|\ (/\//g' | sed 's/)//g'`
```

```
summary1 = $(grep -A 4 '#HM based Segregation FEP (WNS)(TNS)' some_file | awk '{print $2, $3}' | sed 's/,=,//g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/based Segregation,//g' | sed 's/(\|\ (/\//g' | sed 's/)//g')
echo "$summary"
echo "$summary1"
```

basically, I am grepping from some patterns and removing unwanted data.
and the output is

```
summary: Command not found.
Illegal variable name.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form `name=[value]`, with no space before and after the equal sign. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Shell variable assignment syntax is `var=value`. Remove the spaces around the equal. For example:

```sh
summary="$(grep -A 4 '#HM based Segregation FEP (WNS)(TNS)' some_file | awk '{print $2, $3}' | sed 's/,=,//g' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/based Segregation,//g' | sed 's/(\|\ (/\//g' | sed 's/)//g')"
```

Comment: Duplicates should be closed, not answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).